# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl" CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato

Tags: java, curl, exception, processbuilder

I have error in the title, my code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

public class Pro {
    public static void main (String arg[]){
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb2=pb.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Utente\\Downloads\\src"));
            System.out.println(pb2.directory());
            pb2.command("curl", "-X", "POST", "http://10.0.6.96:7877/connect/Nuke");
            pb2.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The curl.exe is in the correct folder, but the java code don't work correctly. Please help me, Thanks you.

Comment: have you tried "curl.exe" as the first argument to the command method?

Comment: Are you sure that Java has access to curl? Please run boolean exists = new File(path-to-curl).exists();

Comment: @Gavin I don't Know.

Comment: @menteith the result is true, therefor exist

Comment: Perhaps you need to give file extensions as well, so `curl.exe`.

Comment: @menteith it don't work with pb2.command("curl.exe", "-X", "POST", "http://10.0.6.96:7877/connect/Nuke");

Comment: Please give full path then, i.e.'C:\\Users\\Utente\\Downloads\\src\\curl.exe'

Comment: @menteith it dosen't work